# "External" navigation to correct angular.js url (direct link/refresh/etc)

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an angular app and have quick question.  As a 'single page app' angular 'takes over' the URL mappings, so I can navigate from "/" -> '/about' etc, and navigations all happen on the client in a single page.

What I am trying to figure out is how to get to the correct page on the client when the client navigation is bypassed.  So for instance, instead of going to http://www.myapp.com, then clicking 'about' and going to 'http://www.myapp.com/about', how do I handle the user going directly to 'http://www.myapp.com/about', I can obviously redirect them to the "/" but I'd still like them to 'end up' at '/about' as that's what they'ed expect. Similarly, there's the same issue on a refresh.  If I'm sitting at '/about', and do a browser refresh, that request is going to '/about' on the server and bypassing the app, so again, need to I guess, reload the app at the root, but still make it back to /about.

Thanks In Advance.

EDIT: 
Thanks for there responses, I think maybe I haven't asked the question clearly.  I understand routing, etc within my angular app.  So setting it up to say load 'partials/about.html' when an '/about' href is clicked.  My issue is that assuming that that is already working, a user goes directly to 'www.myapp.com/about'. The angular application 'lives' on the root.  So presumably, the server would do a redirect to '/'.  That loads the app but doesn't 'set' angular to the route that the user expected.  So the question, is there someway to tell the app "When you load, go to /about" perhaps based on the referrer or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What server are you using ?

You can create a catch-all route in your router.
Like `match '*' => 'Angular#App'` (Rails)

or (express)

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(indexFileContent);
});
```

Comment: I'm using node.js actually so that is cool.  But does that example get the user back to the correct url?  That would just serve the main page back to them right?  Again, I need a request to say '/about' to be redirected to '/' and somehow tell Angular that the user is 'really' at '/about'

Comment: Ok, I had a 'duh' moment.  I've read the location service stuff, etc but it didn't click until now, as did your answer.  Having all url's or at least all 'application' urls (I have an /api root of restful services) just serve the root angular page allows angular to 'figure out' where it's supposed to be when it loads. 

Thanks!

Comment: Also I do just as you, `app.server '/api'` and redirect everything else to Angular. That's a really great solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about client side routing in Angular - not server side. Anyway, my answer is assuming this.

Angular contains a routing service that allows you to define client side routes that map to url's that come after the base server url. Here is an example of how you can set it up:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: '/home-partial', controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
        .when('/about', {templateUrl: '/about-partial', controller: 'AboutCtrl'})
        .when('/contact', {templateUrl: '/contact-partial', controller: 'ContactCtrl'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  }])
```

Provided you have the partials setup on the server side and the controllers setup too, when a user navigates to each url, the correct controller and partial will be pulled up and you can choose to do whatever you need in each of those controllers.

There are other options you can use also, I just use the routes in this way. Check out the AngularJS [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider) for more info